# Display json to textview force close

Tags: java, php, android, json

I want to display product details from mysql database through php and display it in android textview. The scenario is like this: When list of product clicked. it's passed product id to new intent called productdetail. that id will be use for get a detail products in mysql db through php. The PHP file has successfully return data in json format. but when i run program it's keep force closing when open productdetail intent. the problem i found arroud this method new GetProductDetails().execute();
here is my code:

getproductdetail.java

public class ProductDetail extends Activity {

```
TextView txtName;
TextView txtVersion;
TextView txtDesc;
String pid;

//progress dialog
private ProgressDialog pDialog;

//Creating JSON Parser object
JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();

//url to get all products list
private static String url_product_details = "http://visioinformatika.com/demo/appswitcher/bin/get_product_details.php";

// JSON Node names
private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
private static final String TAG_PRODUCTS = "products";
private static final String TAG_PID = "pid";
private static final String TAG_NAME = "product_name";
private static final String TAG_VERSION = "app_version";
private static final String TAG_PDETAIL = "product_detail";

// products JSONArray
JSONArray products = null;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_product_detail);

    // getting product details from intent
        Intent i = getIntent();
    // getting product id (pid) from intent
        pid = i.getStringExtra(TAG_PID);

        //txtName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.app_name);
        //txtName.setText(pid);

    // Getting complete product details in background thread
        new GetProductDetails().execute();

}

/**
 * Background Async Task to Get complete product details
 * */
class GetProductDetails extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    /**
     * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
     * */
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(ProductDetail.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Loading product details. Please wait...");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(true);
        pDialog.show();
    }

    /**
     * Getting product details in background thread
     * */
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

        // updating UI from Background Thread
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                // Check for success tag
                int success;
                try {
                    // Building Parameters
                    List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("pid", pid));

                    // getting product details by making HTTP request
                    // Note that product details url will use GET request
                    JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(
                            url_product_details, "GET", params);

                    // check your log for json response
                    Log.d("Single Product Details", json.toString());

                    // json success tag
                    success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
                    if (success == 1) {
                        // successfully received product details
                        JSONArray productObj = json
                                .getJSONArray(TAG_PRODUCTS); // JSON Array

                        // get first product object from JSON Array
                        JSONObject product = productObj.getJSONObject(0);

                        // product with this pid found
                        // Edit Text
                        txtName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.app_name);
                        txtVersion = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.app_version);
                        txtDesc = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.desc_app);

                        // display product data in TextView
                        txtName.setText(product.getString(TAG_NAME));
                        txtVersion.setText(product.getString(TAG_VERSION));
                        txtDesc.setText(product.getString(TAG_PDETAIL));

                    }else{
                        // product with pid not found
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });

        return null;
    }

    /**
     * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
     * **/
    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
        // dismiss the dialog once got all details
        pDialog.dismiss();
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.product_detail, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

}

here is my php

```
if (isset($_GET["pid"])) {
$pid = $_GET['pid'];

// get a product from products table
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM product WHERE idproduct = '".$pid."'");

if (!empty($result)) {
    // check for empty result
    if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {

        $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);

        $product = array();
        $product["pid"] = $row["idproduct"];
        $product["product_name"] = $row["product_name"];
        $product["product_detail"] = $row["product_detail"];
        $product["app_version"] = $row["app_version"]; 
        // success
        $response["success"] = 1;

        // user node
        $response["product"] = array();

        array_push($response["product"], $product);

        // echoing JSON response
        echo json_encode($response);
    } else {
        // no product found
        $response["success"] = 0;
        $response["message"] = "No product found";

        // echo no users JSON
        echo json_encode($response);
    }
} else {
    // no product found
    $response["success"] = 0;
    $response["message"] = "No product found";

    // echo no users JSON
    echo json_encode($response);
}
} else {
  // required field is missing
  $response["success"] = 0;
  $response["message"] = "Required field(s) is missing";

  // echoing JSON response
  echo json_encode($response);
}
```

This my Crash Log

> 10-15 09:50:32.930: W/dalvikvm(19033): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41534ba8)
>   10-15 09:50:32.930: E/AndroidRuntime(19033): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   10-15 09:50:32.930: E/AndroidRuntime(19033): Process: com.visioinformatika.appswitcher, PID: 19033
>   10-15 09:50:32.930: E/AndroidRuntime(19033): android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
>   10-15 09:50:32.930: E/AndroidRuntime(19033):    at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1145)
>   10-15 09:50:32.930: E/AndroidRuntime(19033):    at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:385)
>   10-15 09:50:32.930: E/AndroidRuntime(19033):    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:236)
>   10-15 09:50:32.930: E/AndroidRuntime(19033):    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:214)
>   10-15 09:50:32.930: E/AndroidRuntime(19033):    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:137)
>   10-15 09:50:32.930: E/AndroidRuntime(19033):    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:164)
>   10-15 09:50:32.930: E/AndroidRuntime(19033):    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:119)
>   10-15 09:50:32.930: E/AndroidRuntime(19033):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:360)
>   10-15 09:50:32.930: E/AndroidRuntime(19033):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:555)
>   10-15 09:50:32.930: E/AndroidRuntime(19033):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:487)
>   10-15 09:50:32.930: E/AndroidRuntime(19033):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:465)
>   10-15 09:50:32.930: E/AndroidRuntime(19033):    at com.visioinformatika.appswitcher.JSONParser.makeHttpRequest(JSONParser.java:62)
>   10-15 09:50:32.930: E/AndroidRuntime(19033):    at com.visioinformatika.appswitcher.ProductDetail$GetProductDetails$1.run(ProductDetail.java:102)
>   10-15 09:50:32.930: E/AndroidRuntime(19033):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
>   10-15 09:50:32.930: E/AndroidRuntime(19033):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>   10-15 09:50:32.930: E/AndroidRuntime(19033):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
>   10-15 09:50:32.930: E/AndroidRuntime(19033):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
>   10-15 09:50:32.930: E/AndroidRuntime(19033):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>   10-15 09:50:32.930: E/AndroidRuntime(19033):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
>   10-15 09:50:32.930: E/AndroidRuntime(19033):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
>   10-15 09:50:32.930: E/AndroidRuntime(19033):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
>   10-15 09:50:32.930: E/AndroidRuntime(19033):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Sorry for my bad english. and I'm new to android :)

Comment: What do you think the `runOnUiThread()` does in your asynctask and how it's related to the `NetworkOnMainThreadException`?

Answer (score 0):

please put this code in postexecute method.UI can not fill in main thread.

```
 // display product data in TextView
                        txtName.setText(product.getString(TAG_NAME));
                        txtVersion.setText(product.getString(TAG_VERSION));
                        txtDesc.setText(product.getString(TAG_PDETAIL));
```

put this line in OnCreate() same as RobinHood saying..

```
 txtName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.app_name);
     txtVersion = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.app_version);
     txtDesc = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.desc_app);
```

Comment: I've put that code in my post execute. but still get error warning. sorry,... im new to android, and little known of java programming.

Comment: I've put that code in my postexecute methode. but it's show error "product cannot be resolved",

Answer (score 0):

You have to improve your coding style, do initialization of views inside *onCreate*.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_product_detail);

     txtName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.app_name);
     txtVersion = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.app_version);
     txtDesc = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.desc_app);
}
```

*If*

You want to update your UI in background then keep tread.

*else*

Do background process inside *doInBackground* and lastly update your view inside *onPostExecute* of asynTask.

Comment: Thank for your advice robbin :), i've initialize textView. but i didnt undrstand about updating view onPostExecute... could you explain it in detailed robbin?

Answer (score 0):

Put This Code in onPreExecute() like shown Below

```
@Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPreExecute();
        // product with this pid found
        // Edit Text
        txtName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.app_name);
        txtVersion = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.app_version);
        txtDesc = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.desc_app);
        pDialog.show();
    }
```